# How to refresh the data while entring date through VBA on webpage?

Tags: excel, vba

Date field is a date picker textbox on webpage. While manually date entered on field, it was refreshed data based on date. below is a HTML code of that particular.
Any help or input would be appreciated. Thanks you!!

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
<input id="_txtFromDt" class="form-control dateselector ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-date" type="text" ng-class="{'isonlyicon':isonlyicon}" ng-change="datePickerChange()" init-date="initialdate" ng-focus="DatePickerFocus()" ng-keypress="isNumeric($event)" ng-blur="checkDate()" ng-disabled="datedisable" default="From Date" key="txtFromDt" name="calDate" maxlength="10" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-model="ngmodels" mxdate="ngmodels" show-button-bar="false" show-weeks="false" close-text="Close" datepicker-options="dateOptions" max-date="maxdate" min-date="mindate" is-open="isopened" title="Enter Date in DD/MM/YYYY Format" placeholder="From Date" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" pageid="" resource="Mx_PageDetail"/>
```

Comment: Not seeing any VBa here?